# Flask Email Support - Get SSLError [Errno 1] when sending email

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, ssl, flask

I'm trying to set up an email server for a Flask app. I'm getting an SSLError. This is my first time learning any sort of web development.

Here is how I've configured the server:

```
# mail server settings
MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MAIL_USE_SSL = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'email@yahoo.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'password'


# administrator list
ADMINS = ['email@yahoo.com']
```

And here is the part of my **init** script that deals with mail:

```
app.config.from_object('config')
mail = Mail(app)
```

Here is the traceback of the error when I try to send an email:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/Users/user/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__
    self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/Users/user/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 156, in configure_host
    host = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 777, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 250, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 310, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 783, in _get_socket
    new_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(new_socket, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)    
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()    
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()   
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Port 587 is for explicit TLS (STARTTLS command) so you probably have to use MAIL_USE_TLS and not MAIL_USE_SSL. MAIL_USE_SSL is for implicit TLS where you directly connect with TLS on port 465.

Comment: So to sum up: Use MAIL_PORT=465, set MAIL_USE_SSL=True and run $ unset MAIL_USE_TLS . This deletes the env. variable. Setting it to False did not do the trick for me.